# unable to install ruby em-websocket: giving fatal error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-16.04, em-websocket

websocket via `gem install em-websocket`. Got this error:

```
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:25:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:233: recipe for target 'binder.o' failed
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
...
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: Do you have `build-essentials` installed? `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: i did that already. i think it is trying to compile with gcc instead of g++.but dont know how to resolve.

Comment: I have tried to copy all the cpp header in the cpp files itself.but still it persist.

Answer (score 0):

iostream was introduced in libstc++-6.Installing libstdc++6-4.4-dev by `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.4-dev`. it will delete currently installed g++.Then run `sudo apt-get install g++`.This solved my problem.